# print preview "div"s duplication

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome, printing, styles

some "div"s shown as duplicate in google chrome print preview -after pressing "Ctrl+P"- , which is not in asp page , in addition to that this case just happen using chrome browser

[image]
for additional information : page is developed using asp.net and css3